# How to handle multi-selection in choice field - Symfony 2

Tags: forms, symfony

**Situation :** I've got following code in one of my forms :

```
        $builder->add('Type', 'choice', array
        (
            'label' => 'Enter body types',
            'choices' => array('Sedan'=>'Sedan','Wagon'=>'Wagon',...),
            'multiple' => true,
        ))
```

**Problem :** When user select multiple values (for example both Sedan and Wagon) the exception 'Array to string conversion' is thrown for obvious reasons.

**Question :** Is there any way to add some form option with function that could handle array to string conversion? I mean something similar to this one :

```
        'someOption' => function ($selectedArray)
        {
           $returnString = "";
           for ($selectedArray as $singleValue){ $returnString = $returnString . ",". $singleValue }
           return $returnString;
        }
```

Comment: how is your entity designed? i mean the entity where the property $type is included.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that your field `Type` is a single string, and in your form you're allowing multiple values.

When a form handles a multiple-selectable field, you're working not with a simple value but with an array of values. When you set this array in your entity field and you try to save this entity in your database, and because your field is designed as a simple string, php will try to get the string version of the value... like that: (string)array(), and this is something that is not doable in PHP :)

You can define your value as an [Array](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/types.html#array-types) or you should disable this multiselection :)

**Note:**

> Your form should handle with arrays if you need to select several
>   values. Your entity should handle this with an array mapping (as I
>   said).